# I am receiving this code in my coding class. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, input, integer, output, expression

```
Exited with return code 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(int1 * int2 * int3)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Trying to output the product of the 3 user inputted integers.

Comment: What code? You only shared the traceback.

Comment: The language I was referring to was Python. Sorry for the confusion and thank you all for the help. I found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are getting the integers using `input()` function.
Do this instead

```
a1 = int(input())
```

This converts the string to integer values